# Python signed license verification using nodejs

Tags: python, node.js, encryption, cryptography

I need to verify a sign value using nodejs. Signed value has created using python. Here is the working piese of code for create and validate. 
The problem is always it gives as not authentic.

Sign created python code:

```
import os
from base64 import b64encode
from pathlib import Path

from Crypto.Hash import SHA512
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Signature import PKCS1_v1_5 as PKCS

if __name__ == "__main__":
    path = Path(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
    file = open('private_key.pem', 'rb')
    private_key = RSA.importKey(file.read())

    msg = "Text to encrypt"

    msg_ = msg.encode('utf-8')

    # RSA Signature Generation
    hash_msg = SHA512.new()
    hash_msg.update(msg_)
    signer = PKCS.new(private_key)
    signature = signer.sign(hash_msg)

    print(b64encode(signature))
```

Sign verification node code:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

var msg = "Text to encrypt"
var hash = crypto.createHash('sha512');
//passing the data to be hashed
hash.update(msg);
console.log("Hash:" + hash);
//Creating the hash in the required format
gen_hash = hash.digest();
var verifier = crypto.createVerify('sha512');
verifier.update(gen_hash);
var ver = verifier.verify(publicKey, sign_value, 'base64');
console.log(ver);
```

Comment: Looks to me like you're hashing twice (why else would have to specify the hash algorithm in createVerify?)

Comment: Please indicate if removing the initial hashing solves the problem. Probably best to close the question if it does.

Comment: @Maarten-reinstateMonica what you mean by initial hashing?

Comment: @Peter createVerify it self need to provide hashing algorithm.

Comment: @Padmasankha, yes, that's what I'm saying. You probably don't have to hash the message yourself.

Comment: In case it is not yet clear, `verifier.update(gen_hash);` already performs the hashing, and you've indicate which one during `createVerify('sha512')`, so `crypto.createHash('sha512')` and subsequent calls to the object can be removed.

Comment: Well, @Peter notified you first of the problem, I just spelled it out :)

Comment: Yes :) thanks @Peter